# Inserting and fetching members from a game grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For a word game, where inside a grid various letters are entered in different tiles ([something similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Bmj.jpg)), I had to create a 6*6 grid (I made them using _ and |) and then do operations on it like:

1. place the tile on a specific location in the grid and
2. return the location of any tile on the grid
3. determining the top scoring words in the grid

Till now I have managed to create the grid, but I have no clue of how to place a tile on a specific grid or fetch the location of a tile on the grid. I have created the following grid:

```
grid = [[" _" for x in range(6)]]
for y in range(6):
    list1 = []
    for x in range(13):
        if x%2 == 0:
            list1.append("|")
        else:
            list1.append("_")
    grid.append(list1)


for row in grid:
    print("".join(row))
```

Comment: Have you actually left space for letters in your grid? I think you may want to leave a space for a letter/cross.

Answer (score 0):

First store only the letters in the grid, so that you can access the items easier by entering the y- and the x-coordinate of the cell:

```
grid[1][2] = 'o'
```

The grid should be a list of lists (the rows) which you can create with a nested list comprehension:

```
grid = [['_' for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(6)]
```

Put the printing code into a function, so that you can just call `print_grid(grid)` to display the grid. Add the pipes and everything else you want to display during the printing, but don't add these things to the actual grid. Here's a complete example:

```
def print_grid(grid):
    print(' _'*len(grid[0]))
    for row in grid:
        for letter in row:
            # Draw pipes followed by the letters on the same line.
            print('|', letter, sep='', end='')
        # Draw the last pipe and go to the next line.
        print('|')

# Use a list of lists for the grid.
grid = [['_' for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(6)]

# Insert letters (y-coordinate first then x).
grid[3][4] = 'x'
grid[1][2] = 'o'
grid[2][2] = 'z'

print_grid(grid)
```